# Page transition using jQuery Animate while having a fix cover image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page that has a fixed header and footer above a wrapper div called 'page'. 'div.page' contains two divs inside it called 'cover' and 'content'. 'div.cover' takes half of the page and is a fixed cover image. 'div.content' takes over the other half and is where my content goes and usually is long and makes the page scrollable. the idea is to keep the cover image in place when you scroll to read the content.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h2>Header</h2>
        <button id="btn">Run Page Transition</button>
    </header>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="cover"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="newpage">
        <div class="cover"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <footer><h2>Footer</h2></footer>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/L5qJW/

I need to transition in a new page called 'div.newpage' which replaces 'div.page'. I have an issue with the animation. In order to keep the new page cover image out of view I need to start with a position of absolute instead of fixed, but once the transition is done, I switch it back to fixed but then I see this "popping back into its place" effect which makes the transition not be smooth.

Any ideas how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `.newpage` to `position:fixed; top:0; height:100%` right off the bat, and get rid of the method changing its position.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L5qJW/8/

Comment: Also, I think it looks a lot smoother if you add `$('.page .content').fadeOut('fast');` right after `e.preventDefault();`.